# How do I select top 10 for each of my two categories in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

**Score**

```
| gender | score |
------------------
|  Man   |   3   |
|  Woman |   2   |
|  Woman |   8   |
|  Man   |   3   |
|  Woman |   7   |
|  Man   |   6   |
|  Man   |   5   |
...
```

How do I select top 10 for each gender. I know that I can union all, but is there any way to do it without using union all?

I want a result like this:

```
| gender | score |
------------------
|  Man   |   12  |
|  Man   |   12  |
|  Man   |   11  |
|  Man   |   11  |
|  Man   |   11  |
... (Top 10 for men)
|  Woman |   13   |
|  Woman |   12   |
|  Woman |   11   |
|  Woman |   11   |
|  Woman |   11   |
... (Top 10 for women)
```

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY score DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT gender, score
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a lateral join to do this.  In this case, it will be much like a UNION ALL but with less repetition in the writing.

```
select tablename.* 
from (values ('Man'),('Woman')) f(gender) 
cross join lateral
(select * from tablename where gender=f.gender order by score desc limit 10) bar;
```

If you have the correct index, it could also be much faster than using the row_number() window function.